# Cauchy problem solution $y'=1-(1+x)y+y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a Cauchy problem $$\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    y'=1-(1+x)y+y^2 \\
    y(0)=1
  \end{array} \right.$$

I'm asked to find $y(x)$ (obviously).

It is farily straightforward to notice a particular solution $y_p(x) = 1+x$, and thus the general solution should be of the form $y_g(x) = u(x) + 1 + x$. As this is a Riccatti's equation it can be brought down to Bernoulli's one and then solved.

I believe I didn't make any mistakes, but my calculations seem to indicate $$y_g(x) = \frac{e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\phi(x)  + C} + 1 + x$$ where $\phi(x) = -\int e^{-x-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx$
Is this correct? I know I didn't include my full solution here (though I checked it twice), but I'm just wondering if this is the result. I'm having doubts as $y_g(0) \neq 1 \ \ \forall C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $y_p(0) = 1$, and $y = y_p$ is a fine solution.

Comment: Your work looks very correct to me and I have much more than a doubt about the condition $y(0)=1$. May be a typo. By the way, you can make $\phi(x)$ explicit (complete the square to arrive to a well known integral and the error function).

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $\phi(x) = -\int e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but since $f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz, by Picard-Lindelof, $y_p$ is the unique solution on some interval containing the origin.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I didn't notice it at first. Great!